# how are multiple parent classes possible?

Tags: php

In a script that I wrote to auto-document the classes of my app, the following function gets parents of the class that's passed in:

```
function getParents($class_name)
{
    $class = new \ReflectionClass($class_name);

    $parents = [];
    while ($parent = $class->getParentClass()):
        $parents[] = $parent->getName();
        $class = $parent;
    endwhile;

    return implode(", ", $parents);
}
```

Having never used `ReflectionClass::getParentClass()` before, the function above was created using the example given in the [PHP manual for this particular reflection class method](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getparentclass.php).

When this function is called in my app, none of the classes are coming back with a comma separated string of parent classes - they have either no parent or a single parent.  Under what circumstances would a class have multiple parents?  Providing a code example to help illustrate such a phenomenon would be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function will return the complete ancestry of a class. For example:

```
class Animal {}
class Mammal extends Animal {}
class Feline extends Mammal {}
class Lion extends Feline {}
```

If you use your `getParents` function on the class `Lion`, you will get the full parent tree up to `Animal`:

```
echo getParents(Lion::class);
// "Feline,Mammal,Animal"
```

https://3v4l.org/IXhQl

Answer (score 4):

The variable `$parents` has a misleading name. `$ancestors` would be better because a PHP class can only have one parent and the code given is finding the one parent, the one grandparent, the one great grandparent, etc. Hopefully your code does not have long chains of inheritance so you only see zero or one ancestor.